# Do honey and cinnamon have anti-inflammatory elements in their biological makeup? What other foods do too?

Tags: anti-inflammatory, antioxidant, honey, vitamin-k, cinnamon

I have an autoimmune disorder wherein my body is constantly inflamed. While I do take anti-inflammatory medications, I am now looking to complement that with my diet.

I heard that cinnamon and honey are made-up of anti-inflammatory agents (maybe antioxidants, potassium, vitamin-k, etc) -- is this true? What other food items could be considered anti-inflammatory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can check MEDLINE and you will find some reports on it,  roibosh tea and several leaves and barks are strong antiinf. drugs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willow_tree